# Samsung android clock app - source code?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

Anyone happen to know if the source to the Android Clock app on Samsung phones is available:
package name is sec.android.app.clockpackage

I've pulled the Samsung source down and the only app in the tree is the Email client (possibly because they tweaked it). So I'm guess the clock app is not opensource - but it's worth asking.

Reason: I really like the Samsung alarm *but* it auto snoozes after 1 minute and if I could change that, it would be perfect.

Same story with most of the alarms on Market - all have something that happens not not be configurable that I could easily tweak if I had the source :(

Cheers

Tim

PS - love android, but disappointed as to how few open source apps are available - unlike desktop/server linux.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to answer my own question:

[Alarm Klock Source](http://code.google.com/p/kraigsandroid/)

[Market link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.angrydoughnuts.android.alarmclock&hl=en)

Is both open source and very hackable. I'll play with that - have already made some minor improvements.